# Speech to text deletes my sentence

Tags: voice-recognition

I am trying to use speak-to-type in QuickOffice, and when I try it at the beginning of item number 2 in a numbered list, it types the sentence and then deletes it again!

If I go up to the existing item number 1 and then try to add my sentence to it using speak-to-type, it works.

Is this a bug?